# ttk:Entry widget disabled background color

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk

I have a ttk Entry which is in "disabled" state.
The background color of the entry field while disabled is a light blue shade.
How can i change it to the default grey color? From this post i understood how we can change the foreground color. 
[tkinter ttk Entry widget -disabledforeground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472501/tkinter-ttk-entry-widget-disabledforeground)

I tried the same method for background color and it did not work.
I am using python 2.7 in Windows 7.

This is the code i tried as per the above said post:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root=Tk()

style=Style()
style.map("TEntry",background=[("active", "black"), ("disabled", "red")])
entry_var=StringVar()
entry=Entry(root,textvariable=entry_var,state='disabled')
entry.pack()
entry_var.set('test')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use styles. You can change the color of disabled entry with option `disabledbackground=<color>`. You can use this option when creating the entry , like:

```
entry.config(background="black",disabledbackground="red")
```

So you overall code(Example) is:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root=Tk()
entry=Entry(root,state='disabled')
entry.config(background="black",disabledbackground="red")
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is a screenshot of the GUI:

[image]

Comment: I apologize, I accidentally down-voted this answer. I can't change my vote unless you edit the answer

Comment: @BryanOakley That is no problem :) . I edited my post.

Comment: The question is talking about `ttk` and you switched it with `tk`.

Answer (score 2):

In ttk and Tk entries widgets, `background` refers to different things. In Tk Entry, `background` refers to the color behind the text, in ttk entry, `background` refers to the color behind the widget. (Yes, I know, confusing right?), what you want to change is `fieldbackground`. So your code would be

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root=Tk()

style=Style()
style.map("TEntry",fieldbackground=[("active", "black"), ("disabled", "red")])
entry_var=StringVar()
entry=Entry(root,textvariable=entry_var,state='disabled')
entry.pack()
entry_var.set('test')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i saw this : http://wiki.tcl.tk/37973. and tried both `background` and `fieldbackground` as you suggested. Both are not working for me

Comment: @newbieuser That is strange it works for me as it is. I'm using python 2.7. Does using the Tkinter Entry widget works for you?

Comment: @newbieuser `entry=Entry(root,textvariable=entry_var,state='disabled')
entry.configure(disabledbackground='red')` without the `import ttk`

Comment: `print(Tkinter.__version__)`
$Revision: 81008 $
`print ttk.__version__`
0.3.1

Comment: yes it is working for Tkinter Entry using `disabledbackground`

Comment: @newbieuser  then I'm really at lost here. I'm sorry I cannot offer more assistance

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639955/806690) suggests that `fieldbackground` is not supported by the Windows style.

Comment: I upvoted this, it works for me. For Python3 I had to make a few changes: lowercase tkinter in import // from tkinter import ttk // add ttk to Style -> ttk.Style() // entry=ttk.Entry. I didn't it get to work with plain " from ttk import * ".

Answer (score -1):

The following code worked for me (but it is with Tk and not with ttk):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Change the default value of disabledbackground for Entry widgets
root.option_add("*Entry.disabledBackground", "lightgray")

# Create a disabled Entry widget
disabled_entry = tk.Entry(root, state="disabled")
disabled_entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```